Using C# process to use commandline read out scrambled
Hi im using Ranorex user code to start a command line and send a newman request.
It works flawless so far up to the point where i print out whats written in the command line process.
in that commandline are alot of weird symbols and only once in a while a readable line.
it also wont show me newmans "nice" stats which it would print u out if u try the same command i sent to wards the newman console via my code.
thats my code:
        lccargscomplete = "run \"" +lccargs+ "\" --insecure --folder \""+requestName+"\"";
        
        Report.Log(ReportLevel.Info,"LCCpath: " + lccpath);
        Report.Log(ReportLevel.Info,"LCCargs: " + lccargscomplete);
        Report.Log(ReportLevel.Info,"Expected: " + returnCode);
      
                
        Process process = new Process();
        process.StartInfo.FileName = lccpath;
        process.StartInfo.Arguments = lccargscomplete;
        process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
        process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
        process.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
                  
        process.OutputDataReceived += OutputDataReceived;
        process.ErrorDataReceived += ErrorDataReceived;
        
        
        
        
        
        process.Start();
        process.BeginOutputReadLine();
        process.BeginErrorReadLine();
        process.WaitForExit();

the lcc args makes the command run "path to newman console" --somevariables for newman nameOftheTest
does anybody have an idea how to "unscramble it"
thats how it looks atm 
i hope somebody has an idea what it could be
i tried to swith to utf-8 idk that didnt do anything beside that i was lucky that what i need was written readable but now i need more precise data
ok sorry took a while thats how its supposed to look 

The <question mark>[90m, <question mark>[39m sequences look like ANSI escape sequences used to change text colors. So maybe it's your console/terminal window that needs to interpret them.

I agree it looks pretty similar. Do u know how i can tell my console to do that by any chance. the standart settings, if thats the problem, should be right cuz when i just open a console and try the command it looks right . gimme a sec i generate a local newman request to show how it should look

What console are you using? That doesn't look like anything standard.

thats just the print out that i get, it reads it out from the console and it looks the same there if i run the command via my code (cant show it rn from the console cuz a collegue "stole" my hardware so thats an old picture of the final report) if i run the same command manuell in a console it looks like the picture i just added

Does the command you're using have any other output options that doesn't include all the console prettying stuff? Would be a lot easier than trying to clean up the current output

After a glance at the docs, you might want to consider using the JSON reporter to get the data.

Again: in your white screenshot, what software is rendering that text? Is it capable of interpreting ANSI escape sequences?

the software is ranorex, i dont think so atleast i cant find anything quickly, i also dont know if it would work with my code especially cuz i need to grab data from that scrambled console

I tried using the json reporter but i cant seem to get that to work, i tried to use it when i needed to download something from postmans answer but i couldnt get it to work

Right, it's highly unlikely that it knows how to handle the ANSI escape sequences it's being sent. It's just not capable of rendering the nice UI table that a proper console can render

but the thing is it already looks like it in the console. if i run the programm it will open a console on my targetsystem. and its scrambeld there already. or do u think that the console ranorex opens is also not able to read it i mean it could be?

@JasminNagel You can either work out how to interpret the terminal control codes (e.g. set the colour, move the cursor to x,y, etc.) or you can try harder to get the JSON reporter to work. What went wrong with it?

the first time i tried it gave me an error(sorry i dont remember the error code anymore) but i tried it on frday again and then it just didnt generate the file like it runned through it but when i checkt the working directory and later the directory i told it to generate the file there was no file

@Andrew Morton i just managed to get it to run again and i rememberd what the problem is if i use json it gives me more or less my collection out and a super long list of numbers like 100k long list

@JasminNagel Did you try any other reporters? E.g., the JUNIT/XML Reporter says "output a summary of the collection run", which sounds like it wouldn't include that long list.

sorry for the late response i found a reporter which worked https://www.npmjs.com/package/newman-reporter-csv
it lets u specify if u want the body or not and makes it readable
